# UPDATE Query with GROUP BY in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have below table and I need to Update two columns which are `IsCurrent` and `PhotoID`

[image]

Logic behind the update is as follows:

- User is sending `PhotoId` value and we need to update `PhotoID` column which is empty
- To Update `IsCurrent` column we have to get the maximum date of `CreationDate` of certain `ProcessId` (`GROUP BY ProcessId`) and Update that record as "Y" and rest of the records as "N" for the same `ProcessID`

Expected output as bellow:

[image]

I would like to know the best way to write this UPDATE query for this scenario. I tried `SWITCH CASE` , `UPDATE with GROUP BY` and didn't work.

I want to avoid using a LOOP since it impacts Performance

Comment: Include what you tried in your question. Show your attempt(s), explain why they didn't work. Seems like, however, what you actually want might be an updatable CTE.

Comment: There is no `SWITCH CASE` in tsql. And the "best" way to do this is to set the columns as needed when the rows are inserted - not after the fact when you have lots of rows that need to be updated. But your logic is basically a "first in group" situation - a term you can use for a web search. Using row_number you can order by creation date desc; row 1 will be the "current" one and every other will not. Don't know why the same photo ID value is assigned to every row but that logic is trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
UPDATE P
SET P.PhotoID = 5,
    P.IsCurrent = CASE WHEN S.RN = 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
FROM Table P
JOIN 
( 
  SELECT ID, ProcessID, CreationDate, IsCurrent, PhotoID,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProcessID ORDER BY CreationDate DESC) RN
  FROM Table
)S ON P.ID = S.ID
```

Comment: Vignesh, you need to add `on s.id = p.id` at end of your code and correct `PhotID` to `PhotoID` in join subquery.

Comment: @MarkoIvkovic Yes

Comment: @VigneshKumarA Very sorry for the late reply. Query you provided helped me a lot. Had to alter ``P.PhotoID= 5`` with CASE WHEN since it update all the PhotoID but I wanted only to update ``NULL`` PhotoID